# Storing image path in plist then retrieve to show on screen

Tags: xcode, swift, plist, property-list

I am trying to make an app where the picture comes up with the anagram of a word. I have the anagram part but I can't get the picture to come up. The picture is saved in a folder called "images". I would like to call anagramPics - item 0, at the same time as anagrams -item 0 - to match the word with the pic

Thanks in advance.

[image: I would like to call anagramPics - item 0, at the same time as anagrams -item 0 - to match the word with the pic]

code for the anagram:

level.m

```
#import "Level.h"

@implementation Level

+(instancetype)levelWithNum:(int)levelNum;
{
 // find .plist file for this level
  NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%i.plist", levelNum];
  NSString* levelPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]      stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

  // load .plist file
  NSDictionary* levelDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:levelPath];

  // validation
  NSAssert(levelDict, @"level config file not found");

  // create Level instance
  Level* l = [[Level alloc] init];

  // initialize the object from the dictionary
  l.pointsPerTile = [levelDict[@"pointsPerTile"] intValue];
  l.anagrams = levelDict[@"anagrams"];
  l.timeToSolve = [levelDict[@"timeToSolve"] intValue];

  return l;
}

@end
```

level.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Level : NSObject

//properties stored in a .plist file
@property (assign, nonatomic) int pointsPerTile;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int timeToSolve;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* anagrams;

//factory method to load a .plist file and initialize the model
+(instancetype)levelWithNum:(int)levelNum;

@end
```

gameController.h

```
-(void)dealRandomAnagram
{
//1
NSAssert(self.level.anagrams, @"no level loaded");

//2 random anagram
int randomIndex = arc4random()%[self.level.anagrams count];
NSArray* anaPair = self.level.anagrams[ randomIndex ];

//3
NSString* anagram1 = anaPair[0];
NSString* anagram2 = anaPair[1];

//4
int ana1len = [anagram1 length];
int ana2len = [anagram2 length];

//5
NSLog(@"phrase1[%i]: %@", ana1len, anagram1);
NSLog(@"phrase2[%i]: %@", ana2len, anagram2);    
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I don't see any code that is trying to show an image.

Comment: that's what I am having problems with. I do not know how to call it at all.

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of images? Do you know all the names of the image files?

Comment: yes I have a fixed set of images, they are all located in one folder  and they all have names like "cat.jpg, dog.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar situation where I have some fixed images to display. This is what I did.

Added a UIImageView on Storyboard. Positioned it out where I wanted it using constraints etc.

Created an IBOutlet for it. Call it myImageView.

I added all my images as assets.  In my case I'm displaying various credit card images but the principle is the same.

[image: Click on Images.xcassets]

[image: Credit card image assets]

[image: Looks like this in Xcode]

Each image asset is a folder with a Contents.json file and the image files that go with it. You will note that there are three files. iOS will use the correct size image for retina, iPhone 6plus etc.

Contents.json looks like this:

```
{
    "images" : [
        {
            "idiom" : "universal",
            "scale" : "1x",
            "filename" : "card-visa@1x.png"
        },
        {
            "idiom" : "universal",
            "scale" : "2x",
            "filename" : "card-visa@2x.png"
        },
        {
            "idiom" : "universal",
            "scale" : "3x",
            "filename" : "card-visa@3x.png"
        }
    ],
    "info" : {
        "version" : 1,
        "author" : "xcode"
    }
}
```

[image: asset folder]

In the code, change the image of the UIViewImage by setting its image property.

(This is Swift code. You will have to convert it to Objective-C yourself.)

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"Card VISA")
```

Comment: where exactly did you put your code for this? It's actually a good idea! so thank you!

Comment: In my case it is in a tableview, so it is in tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath. I can't tell you where to put it because that depends on how your application is structured. If you are using a button to change the image, then put it in the IBAction of that button.